# Rails 6.0 で label の表記が変わらない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

一つのフォームで複数のモデルのレコードを更新できるように実装したいのですが、labelの表記がうまく反映されません。
`time_tables`テーブルのレコードと`artistsテーブル`のレコードを同時に保存したいため、モデルとコントローラーは以下のコードにしています。

```rb
class TimeTable < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :schedules # 複数のScheduleを持っている(中間テーブル)
  has_many :artists, through: :schedules # 複数のArtistを持っていて、中間モデルにSchedulesがある
  belongs_to :user # Userモデルに属している

  validates_associated :artists # Artistモデルのバリデーションを実行
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :artists, allow_destroy: true # Artistモデルを更新、削除刷ることができる
end
```

```rb
  def new
    @time_table = TimeTable.new
    10.times do
      @time_table.artists.build
    end
  end
```

一括登録の仕方がわからなかったのでtimes.doを使い、**artistテーブル**のモデルを１０回作成しようとしています。
erbファイルは以下のように記載しているのですが、ループ文が使われているため、フォーム欄は複数できるのですが、ラベルの表記が全部同じになってしまいます。

```html
# 抜粋
     <div class="form-row">
       <%= f.fields_for :artists do |a| %>
        <div class='form-group'>
          <%= a.label :name, '10:00' %>
          <%= a.text_field :name, class:'form-control' %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
```

ラベルだけループさせずに、それぞれのフォームに合わせたラベルを作成したいのですが、どのように実装したらよいかわからないので、教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 0):

まず、accepts_nested_attributes_for は Rails によって提供されている機能ではありますが、非常に嫌われている半ば非推奨な機能です
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/26976#discussion_r87855694

> I'd actually like to kill accepts_nested_attributes_for in due time.

なので

1. formでやり取りするデータに対応する Form Object クラスを作成
2. コントローラーでフォームから送信された値を使って Form Object を new
3. Form Object 経由でデータベースに保存

とするのが望ましいと思います

仮に accepts_nested_attributes_for を使って実現するとしたら

まず accepts_nested_attributes_for は Rails によって提供されている機能ではありますが、非常に嫌われている半ば非推奨な機能です

- formでやり取りするデータに対応する Form Object クラスを作成
- コントローラーでフォームから送信された値を使って Form Object を new
- Form Object 経由でデータベースに保存

とするのが望ましいと思います

仮に accepts_nested_attributes_for を使って実現するとしたら

```ruby
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources 'foos'
end

# app/models/foo.rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :bar,
           dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bar,
                                allow_destroy: true

  # fields_for に accepts_nested_attributes_for + has_many 
  # 組み合わせであることを伝えるために必要
  def bars_attributes=(attributes)
  end
end

# app/models/bar.rb
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :foo,
             optional: true
end

# app/controllers/foos_controller.rb
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @foo = Foo.new
    # 3コ子要素を作る
    @foo.bar.build
    @foo.bar.build
    @foo.bar.build
  end

  def create
    params.permit!
    @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo])
    @foo.save!
  end
end
```

```erb
<%# app/views/foos/new.html.erb %>
<%= form_with(model: @foo) do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <%= f.fields_for(:bar, :bar) { |f_bar| %>
      <li>index: <%= f_bar.index %></li>
      <li>name: <%= f_bar.text_field :name %></li>
    <% } %>
  </ul>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>


<%# app/views/foos/create.html.erb %>
<% @foo.bar.each { |bar| %>
  <p><%= bar.name %></p>
<% } %>
```

のような感じになると思います

正直、このコードも fields_for のソースコードを読みながら書いたので、今後どのバージョンアップで壊れてもおかしくありません
accepts_nested_attributes_for の利用は止めたほうが無難です